# how i can use the PDO results?

Tags: php, pdo

Hello every one i'm trying to do a login method for my website, and i'm having a small problem. I'm getting the data from PDO connection but every time im checking the password it returns false. is my variables wrong?
here is my sql query

```
$this->result = $this->sql->prepare('SELECT username,password FROM User WHERE username=:username AND password=:password');
$this->result->bindParam(':username',   $username,  PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$this->result->bindParam(':password',   $password,  PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$this->result->execute();
```

and here is my if statement:

```
$this->result=$this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if (($password == $this->result->password) && ($username == $this->result->username)){
```

i'm not getting error it just return always false. i'm not encrypting the password yet so is not this problem. i think $this->result->password is the problem. can anyone correct me please?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as well:

```
$username=$_GET['username'];$password = $_GET['password'];/*of $_POST, depending of which you used*/
$this->result = $this->sql->prepare('SELECT username,password FROM User WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password');
```

$this->result->execute();

And then use `fetchAll` like this:

```
$this->results = $this->result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($this->results['username']==$this->username && $this->results['password']==$this->password){/*u had beed loged in*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should work. Most likely, the SQL is not returning anything. Try printing out the result of your fetch.

```
$this->result=$this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($this->result);
```

Also, if you are checking for username and password in the SQL query, you don't have to check it again in the if statement. With the SQL statement you are using, you should be able to just check if it returned a row or not to validate the user.

```
$numrows = $this->result->rowCount();
if ($numrows == 1) {
  // User is valid
}
else {
  // User is not valid
}
```

Comment: Checking the row count after querying for the log in details to match, is a way I use most often, should be efficient enough for your purpose and remember if your going to a live server with this to hash your passwords from plain text. :)

Comment: i tried all the ways but is not working. i change the fetch to fetchAll nothing, i changed the FETCH_OBJ to FETCH_ASSOC nothing again. i made a print of the $this->result->password and cites empty!!

Comment: @George If $this->result is not returning anything, then there are probably no record matching your query. Try going into mysql directly and execute the sql to see if any results are showing. 

"SELECT username,password FROM User WHERE username='user' AND password='pass';"

where "user" and "pass" are the value of the variables $username and $password respectively. 

Perhaps try echoing $username and $password to see if they are not empty and is assigned an appropriate value from $_POST or $_GET.

Comment: i found the problem guys. i had to change the $this->result to something else because i had 2 sql queries to executed at the same time. so the password had the sql query and the password as values